# XSLT replace an element that exists inside another element value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, transformation

I am new to XSLT (using XSLT v1.0) and I have the following input:

```
<SUMMARY>
<TITLE>Lorem ipsum dolor <QUOTE ID="replace with this string"/> sit vel eu. 
</TITLE>
<P> Lorem ipsum dolor <QUOTE ID="replace with this string"/> sit vel eu. </P>
</SUMMARY>

<REFERENCE>
<TI>Lorem ipsum dolor <QUOTE ID="replace with this string"/> sit vel eu. 
</TI>
<P> Lorem ipsum dolor <QUOTE ID="replace with this string"/> sit vel eu. </P>
</REFERENCE>
```

How could I replace all the occurrences of the element QUOTE inside my XML input, with a String that is the value of the QUOTE/ID attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the identity transform a special template to handle `QUOTE`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="QUOTE">
      <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The identity transformation will copy everything to the output XML, and the special `QUOTE` template will copy over the value of its `@ID` attribute in place of the `QUOTE` element.

Comment: That was exactly what i needed. Thank you that made XSLT much more clear to me.